# Proving n + S n = S (n + n) without n + S m = S (n + m)

Tags: logic, coq, proof, theorem-proving

Is it possible to prove `forall n, n + S n = S (n + n)` (with or without induction) without using `forall n m, n + S m = S (n + m)`?

Looking at the proof, if I start by using induction on `n`, we end up in a state where the inductive hypothesis is too weak (similar to the problem of inducting on n for a given m):

```
n: nat
IHn: n + S n = S (n + n)
1/1
n + S (S n) = S (n + S n)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a perhaps boring answer: yes, by reducing the problem to `forall n m, n + S m = S (n + m)`:

```
Goal forall n, n + S n = S (n + n).
Proof.
  intros n.
  generalize n at 2 4 as m.
(*
goal is now:
  n : nat
  ============================
  forall m : nat, n + S m = S (n + m)
*)
Abort.
```

However, I'm not sure this is what you were asking. Perhaps you want to know whether `forall n, n + S n = S (n + n)` implies `forall n m, n + S m = S (n + m)` in some weak theory where the latter is not outright provable. For example, we can ask whether `forall n, P n n` implies `forall n m, P n m` for a generic `P`, and then the answer is obviously "no". The answer then seems to depend on what you want to assume about addition and `S`. Their usual definitions are too strong for this problem because `forall n m, n + S m = S (n + m)` is already provable and anything implies a provable statement.